# How can a specific lens in darktable be selected which is mounted using an adapter?

Tags: darktable

Is it possible to select a specific lens in darktable (2.6)? 
When my camera is detected by darktable the lens correction module offers only e-mount (sony native) lenses.

I'm using a few old Minolta MD lenses which seem to be supported by [lensfun](http://lensfun.sourceforge.net/lenslist/) (software library).

I also tried to set the camera to a generic full-frame but I'm still not able to find the old Minoltas.

[image]

Comment: If you are using a tilt adapter, as indicated by your other question, the point is pretty much moot. When the lens is tilted the correction profile will not be the same for either geometric distortion or vignetting as when the lens is aligned with its optical axis perpendicular to the imaging plane (sensor/film).

Comment: @MichaelC For these lenses I'm using a plain MD/Nex Adapter with no tilt or other extras. I just like experimenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command line tool `lensfun-add-adapter` for this, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/lensfun-add-adapter.1.html.

You can also do it by hand.  Add a file `_mounts.xml` to a directory where Lensfun searches for your personal XMLs (it’s `~/.local/share/lensfun` on Linux, I don’t know the path on Windows) with the following content:

```
<lensdatabase>
    <mount>
        <name>Sony E</name>
        <compat>DKL</compat>
        <compat>Generic</compat>
        <compat>M42</compat>
        <compat>Sony Alpha</compat>
        <compat>T2</compat>
        <compat>Minolta MD</compat>
    </mount>
</lensdatabase>
```

Comment: Thanks the cmdline tool is not shipped in my windows distribution, I tried to edit the definition files found in C:\Program Files\darktable26\share\lensfun\version_1 but this seems not be read or updated by darktable. And this feature isn't implemented yet: https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/11726

Comment: This feature won’t help you anyway because you need a Lensfun code update rather than a Lensfun DB update.

Comment: Thank you, now at least 2 of the Minolta MD show up for the A6000 (crop) but none for A7RII both have the same <compat>Minolta MD</compat> xml element though.

Comment: Maybe missing lenses have only been calibrated for the other crop factor?